# Angular JS ng-show expression not working

Tags: angularjs

Condition is not working properly

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<span ng-show ="myAngApp1.vlaue == customer.LSpanish">
                 {{customer.LSpanish}}
                 </span>
                  <span ng-show="myAngApp1.value == customer.LChinese">
                     {{customer.LChinese}}
                 </span>
```

Comment: `ng-show` directive value should not use `{{}}`(interpolation directive), it will just provide a expression, which will evaluate against current scope..

Comment: @PankajParkar {{Customer.LCChinese}} ->  ΤΑΜΕΙΟ(View Source) myAngApp1.vlaue -> "ΤΑΜΕΙΟ"(Developer Console) but still display: none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this:

```
<span ng-show="myAngApp1.value ==customer.LChinese">
        {{customer.LChinese}}
</span>
```

Just remove the interpolation.

Comment: tried but not working and find my comment above for value...thanks

Comment: `myAngApp1.value` is not a scope variable?

Comment: yeah its value I am getting from javascript element by ID

Comment: `$scope`  element or not. If not just do `$scope.myAngApp1.value = myAngApp1.value;`

Comment: tried this but not working $scope.myAngApp1 = myAngApp1;

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have valid value in controller and if view is being loaded after few operation use $scope.$apply()

Controller-

```
      $scope.myAngApp1.vlaue = "ΤΑΜΕΙΟ";
      $scope.customer.LSpanish = "ΤΑΜΕΙΟ";
```

View -

```
 <span ng-show ="myAngApp1.vlaue == customer.LSpanish">
                 {{customer.LSpanish}}
    </span>
    <span ng-show="myAngApp1.vlaue == customer.LChinese">
                     {{customer.LChinese}}
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the correct synthax:

```
<span ng-show="myAngApp1.value == customer.LSpanish">
```